# Add object to an object from a function in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

First I hit the button `Add` then 'Show' and lastly `Show Object`

The problem is that when I hit the button `Show Object` I get only one object for the last input element instead one object for each input element.

How can I add new objects from inside a function without loosing most of them?

Here is the code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  // body...
  var tableInput = "<tr><td><input type='text'/></td><td><input type='text'/></td></tr>";
  var obj = {};
  const rowNo = 2;

  $("h1").text("Helllo Sonq");
  console.log("function called!");

  $("#add").click(function() {
    $("#table").append(tableInput)
  })

  $("#show").click(function() {
    $(":text").each(function(index) {
      console.log(index + ': ' + $(this).val());
      var rowno = "row" + parseInt(index / rowNo)
      obj[rowno] = new Object()
      obj[rowno]["element" + index.toString()] = $(this).val();
      // obj[rowno]["element" + index.toString()] = $(this).val();
    })
  })

  $("#show-object").click(function() {
    console.log(obj);
  })
})
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Page Title</title>
</head>

<body>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/js.js"></script>
  <h1>Hello Riko!</h1>
  <button id="add">Add</button>
  <button id="show">Show</button>
  <button id="show-object">Show Object</button>
  <table id="table">
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Age</th>
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>

</html>
```

Into the function :

```
$("#show").click(function(){
    $(":text").each(function(index) {
```

I want to add an object to the global `obj` for each iterated `input type=text` element.

Comment: What output do you expect?

Comment: `var rowno = "row" + parseInt(index/rowNo)`  What are you trying to achieve here? you are trying to divide `index` with `rowNo` and assign it to `rowNo`?

Comment: if the input text elements are two for example I expect: {obj: {row0: {element0: "text-input2", element1: "text-input2"}}}

Comment: The expression `index/rowNo` will always be `NaN`.

Comment: There are 2 text fields per roll. I want an object that reflects the structure of the table. Row0 would have element0 and element1, then Row1 would have element0 and element1 and so on

Comment: rowNo is 2 not 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first time you do `var rowno = "row" + parseInt(index/rowNo)` , var rowno is filled with row0. Since 0/2 is 0.

But then, the second time, the same row, `var rowno = "row" + parseInt(index/rowNo)` gives you also a value of 0, since 1/2 does 0.5, wich gets truncated to 0. By doing so, you are replacing the object at position 'row0', wich is what an object in javascript does.

You should not use parseInt

Comment: The example above is only for demonstration, If I omit this line: `obj[rowno] = new Object()` I get the error `Cannot set property 'subSubObj0' of undefined`. How on earth In javaScript one can APPEND object to an object?

Comment: So ... the other guy steals my answer and gets the answer LOL

Comment: You were first - Fixed :D

Comment: @BabaNew you mentioned, "You should not use parseInt".  if parseInt() is not be used then first time row0 & second time it should row0.5 (rowno is changed)?

Comment: @SajibKhan since paraseInt is leading to this undesired behaviour, it should be avoided in favor of other approaches

Comment: @BabaNew I appreciate you got the problem first, but the solution was not correct. Better you can edit your answer so future SO comer would not be confused.

Answer (score 2):

Since you target the rows then you should loop through them first then inside every row loop throug the inputs just like :

```
$("tbody>tr").each(function(index) {
  var rowno = "row" + index;
  obj[rowno] = {};

  $(":text", this).each(function(index) {
    console.log(index + ': ' + $(this).val());

    obj[rowno]["element" + index] = $(this).val();
  });
});
```

**NOTE :** My suggestion adjust also the table using `thead/tbody`.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var tableInput = "<tr><td><input type='text'/></td><td><input type='text'/></td></tr>";
  var obj = {};
  const rowNo = 2;

  $("h1").text("Helllo Sonq");
  console.log("function called!");

  $("#add").click(function() {
    $("#table>tbody").append(tableInput)
  })

  $("#show").click(function() {
    $("tbody>tr").each(function(index) {
      var rowno = "row" + index;
      obj[rowno] = {};

      $(":text", this).each(function(index) {
        console.log(index + ': ' + $(this).val());

        obj[rowno]["element" + index] = $(this).val();
      })
    })
  })

  $("#show-object").click(function() {
    console.log(obj);
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<h1>Hello Riko!</h1>
<button id="add">Add</button>
<button id="show">Show</button>
<button id="show-object">Show Object</button>
<table id="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Age</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody></tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just create `obj[rowno] = new Object()` if it does not exist:

```
if (!obj[rowno]) {
  obj[rowno] = new Object()
}
```

because it is recreating the new instance so, the previous one has vanished.

```
$("#show").click(function() {
  $(":text").each(function(index) {
    console.log(index + ': ' + $(this).val());
    var rowno = "row" + parseInt(index / rowNo)
    if (!obj[rowno]) {
      obj[rowno] = new Object()
    }
    obj[rowno]["element" + index.toString()] = $(this).val();
  })
})
```

**N.B.**

> parseInt(index / 2) returns 0 when index = 0
>    parseInt(index / 2) returns 0 when index = 1

Comment: The other workarounds would do the job as well, but due to my BAD example, the didn't understand that I wanted to know want happens really, not how to get the job done. Now I get what happens :O, Tricky for noobsies like me :D.